# how do you dynamically add sliderInput to your shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny

using shiny, I am uploading a csv file and based on column names, I need to add slider to the ui.

```
                        sidebarPanel(
                                  fileInput('file1', 'Upload CSV File to Create a Model',
                                            accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
                                  tags$hr(),
                                  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(6,checkboxGroupInput("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"))),
                                    column(6,radioButtons("yaxisGrp","Y-axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
                                  ),
                                  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                               c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
                                  radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                               c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
                                  uiOutput("choose_columns")
                                )
```

As you can see, there is xaxisGrp and yaxisGrp. xasixGrp has the column names in my uploaded csv file.

I need to dynamically add as many sliderInput as possible in xasisGrp minus the column name in yaxisGrp. For example, lets say

```
xasisGrp has "Heap", "CPU", "Volume",
```

I need to be able to generate 3 sliderInput like this:

```
sliderInput("Heap", "Heap Growth %",min=0, max=100, value=0,post="%"),
sliderInput("CPU", "CPU Growth %", min=0, max=100, value=0,post="%"),
sliderInput("Volume", "Volume Growth%", min=0, max=100, value=0,post="%"),
```

Any ideas how I could do this Shiny?

Comment: Here is an example for dynamically generating multiple `textInput`, but the idea is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141451/ammending-dynamic-input-code-in-r-shiny/36143511#36143511 You need to use `uiOutput` in `ui.R`, `renderUI`, `lapply` and `do.call` in `server.R`.

Comment: @warmoverflow, I look at the post about textInput, not following it. Would you be able to start me off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example.

```
library(shiny)

xAxisGroup <- c("Heap", "CPU", "Volume")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Dynamic sliders"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          # Create a uiOutput to hold the sliders
        uiOutput("sliders")
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    #Render the sliders
    output$sliders <- renderUI({
        # First, create a list of sliders each with a different name
        sliders <- lapply(1:length(xAxisGroup), function(i) {
            inputName <- xAxisGroup[i]
            sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0, post="%")
        })
        # Create a tagList of sliders (this is important)
        do.call(tagList, sliders)
    })


   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(100), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: slider bar is too small, I cannot tell whether it is working or not?

Comment: one quick question. I need to reference these sliders in another function to do some other work. I need to go though each slider value and calculate some other think.

Comment: Just use the value like a normal input `input$Heap` etc

Comment: @XiongbingJin Thanks very helpful.. Do you, or anyone else, have a purrr alternative to the lapply/do.call approach