# Number of sliderInputs and names depend on the unique values from a selectInput choice in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a `shiny` app where the user selects a variable from a drop down box, e.g. `dose` or `supp` in the `toothgrowth` dataset. If the user selects `dose` there is then a slider from 1 to 100 for each unique dose, 0.5, 1, 2 and if the user selects `supp` there is a slider for OJ and VC.

My problem is I cannot make those sliders work. I have been trying to use the example in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977499/how-do-you-dynamically-add-sliderinput-to-your-shiny-application) but it is not working.

Here is the code.

```
library(shiny)

data("ToothGrowth")

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4, 
             selectInput("group", "Group:", 
                                       c("supp" = "Supp",
                                         "dose" = "Dose")),
             uiOutput("sliders")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer( function(input, output) { 

  dat<-reactive({
    unique(ToothGrowth[,input$group])
  })


  #Render the sliders
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    # First, create a list of sliders each with a different name
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(dat()), function(i) {
      inputName <- dat()[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0)
    })
    # Create a tagList of sliders (this is important)
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ui` you need to match the strings with the column names exactly (note placement of capital letters):

```
selectInput("group", "Group:", 
                         c("Supp" = "supp",
                           "Dose" = "dose"))
```

In addition, your `dat` will be a factor when you subset your data (for `supp`). Would want a vector of strings that will work in your `sliderInput` statement.

Try the following:

```
server <- shinyServer( function(input, output) { 

  dat<-reactive({
    as.character(unique(ToothGrowth[,input$group]))
  })


  #Render the sliders
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
    # First, create a list of sliders each with a different name
    sliders <- lapply(1:length(dat()), function(i) {
      inputName <- dat()[i]
      sliderInput(inputName, inputName, min=0, max=100, value=0)
    })
    # Create a tagList of sliders (this is important)
    do.call(tagList, sliders)
  })
})
```