# R Shiny store the user input from multiple dynamically generated textAreaInput fields in an object in the server part

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, textarea, user-input

New to `shiny` and struggling with this for more than two days now.
I have created an application where the user loads `.csv` data file and chooses one or more variables whose names appear in the application as check boxes. When a checkbox is checked, a new checkbox appears under with the same name and when it is clicked too, a `textAreaInput` appears next to it where the user can add variable names that constitute the target variable as a scale. Here is an oversimplified version of the application:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose File", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".csv"),
    uiOutput(outputId = "varCheckBoxesIndivScores"),

    column(width = 3,
           uiOutput(outputId = "selectedScoresCheckBoxes")),

    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectedScoresCheckBoxes",
                     column(width = 6,
                            uiOutput(outputId = "variablesConstitutingScale"))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  df <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      tbl <- fread(input$file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      return(tbl)
    }
  })

  output$varCheckBoxesIndivScores <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df())) {
      return(tags$div(align = "left",
                      class = "multicol",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "varCheckBoxesIndivScores",
                                         label = "Select variables",
                                         choices = colnames(df()))))
    }
  })

  output$selectedScoresCheckBoxes <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df())) {
      return(tags$div(align = "left",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "selectedScoresCheckBoxes",
                                         label = "",
                                         choices = input$varCheckBoxesIndivScores)))
    }
  })

  output$variablesConstitutingScale <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df()) & length(input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes > 0)) {
      var.list.input.fields <- lapply(input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes, function(i) {
        textAreaInput(inputId = "i", label = paste("Variables constituting scale", i), width = "700px", height = "100px", value = NULL)
      })
      var.list.input.fields
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The data to load is generated like this (just an excerpt, the real one has more columns and cases):

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.table(ID = c(2201:2220), VAR1 = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 2),
VAR2 = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 20), VAR3 = 1:20, VAR4 = 21:40,
VAR5 = 41:60, VAR6 = 61:80, VAR7 = 81:100)

write.csv(x = x, file = "/tmp/test_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

It works fine, no errors. Here is how it looks, after I enter the variable names in each of the generated `textAreaInput` fields:
[image]

However, I would like to take the user input from each dynamically generated `textAreaInput` and store it in a list like:

```
list(VAR1 = "VAR3 VAR4 VAR5", VAR2 = "VAR6 VAR7")
```

or

```
list(VAR1 = "VAR3", "VAR4", "VAR5", VAR2 = "VAR6", "VAR7")
```

inside the server part of the application for future use.

I tried to follow the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141451/ammending-dynamic-input-code-in-r-shiny) thread, but I did not succeed to come to any solution and feel quite confused. Can someone help?

Comment: (just a comment, nothing to do with an answer). That does not look very convenient. I would use [shinyTree](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTree) to do the selections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you want to make sure to assign each of your dynimcally added elements to have a unique name. You have just hard coded the letter "i" in the sample. You want something like

```
textAreaInput(inputId = paste0("varconst_",i), label = paste("Variables constituting scale", i), 
    width = "700px", height = "100px", value = NULL)
```

Then you can observe those text boxes with something like this

```
observeEvent(lapply(paste0("varconst_", input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes), function(x) input[[x]]), {
  obj <- Map(function(x) input[[paste0("varconst_",x)]], input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes)
  dput(obj)
})
```

Here I just used `dput` to dump the list to the console so you can see it as it gets updated but you can do whatever you want with that.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. Indeed, I was not thinking about the uniqueness of the names. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code of the application as per MrFlick's answer. To leave a paper trail of the complete solution, I am posting it below. The few additional modifications I have made include the printout of the list with the variables for each of the generated `textAreaInput` fields, so that the list can be viewed in the application itself. I have also added some further modifications of the `obj`, after it is generated, to obtain the list as desired.

If there are more dynamically generated output sections where check boxes and related text areas, the `varconst_` index has to be made unique across the different chunks of code (e.g. `varconst1_`, `varconst2_`, `varconst3_`, etc.).

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose File", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".csv"),
    uiOutput(outputId = "varCheckBoxesIndivScores"),

    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3,
             uiOutput(outputId = "selectedScoresCheckBoxes")),

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectedScoresCheckBoxes",
                       column(width = 6,
                              uiOutput(outputId = "variablesConstitutingScale")))),
    br(),

    fluidRow(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.selectedScoresCheckBoxes",
                       verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "scalesVarList")))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  df <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      tbl <- fread(input$file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      return(tbl)
    }
  })

  output$varCheckBoxesIndivScores <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df())) {
      return(tags$div(align = "left",
                      class = "multicol",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "varCheckBoxesIndivScores",
                                         label = "Select variables",
                                         choices = colnames(df()))))
    }
  })

  output$selectedScoresCheckBoxes <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df())) {
      return(tags$div(align = "left",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "selectedScoresCheckBoxes",
                                         label = "",
                                         choices = input$varCheckBoxesIndivScores)))
    }
  })

  output$variablesConstitutingScale <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df()) & length(input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes > 0)) {
      var.list.input.fields <- lapply(input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes, function(i) {
        textAreaInput(inputId = paste0("varconst_",i), label = paste("Variables constituting scale", i), 
                      width = "700px", height = "100px", value = NULL)
      })
      var.list.input.fields
    }
  })

  observeEvent(lapply(paste0("varconst_", input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes), function(x) input[[x]]), {
    obj <- Map(function(x) input[[paste0("varconst_",x)]], input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes)
    obj <- sapply(obj, function(i) {
      if(length(i) > 0) {
        strsplit(x = i, split = " ")
      }
    })
    dput(obj)
    output$scalesVarList <- renderPrint({
      if(is.null(df())) {
        return(NULL)
      } else if(!is.null(df()) && length(input$selectedScoresCheckBoxes) > 0 && length(obj) > 0) {
        print(obj)
      }
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```