# Exclude all inputs from Shiny bookmarks

Tags: r, shiny

I have a custom bookmark URL for my shiny app. I use `setBookmarkExclude()` to exclude all inputs (i.e. widgets). Then I use `onBookmark()` to build a bookmark URL and `onRestore()` to restore the state.

During development, if new widgets are added, their IDs also have to be added to the `setBookmarkExclude()` function. If not, then the bookmark URL will change.

Is there a proper way to exclude all inputs?

Initially I tried `setBookmarkExclude(names(input))` but this doesn't work since this function is called from inside the application's server function when `input` is not yet initialized.

Obviously, an opposite function `setBookmarkInclude(NULL)` would be ideal?

Comment: Please check the whitelist approach I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825515/9841389). Even though I'm not sure if it helps in your specfic case since you haven't provided any example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, your answer gave me the idea to do it this way: `observe({setBookmarkExclude(names(input))}, priority = 100, autoDestroy = TRUE)` which works. From documentation I thought I had to place `setBookmarkExclude()` in the server function to be executed during initialisation. Seems not so. You can post your answer if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already mentioned using `setBookmarkExclude(names(input))`, which is the right way to go.

The key is to dynamically use `setBookmarkExclude` wrapped in an observer.

This is a modified version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816861/shinyjs-setbookmarkexclude-for-delay-ids/55825515#55825515) showing how to exclude dynamically generated inputs:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    br(),
    bookmarkButton(id = "bookmarkBtn"),
    actionButton(inputId = "addSlider", label = "Add slider..."),
    hr(),
    textOutput("ExcludedIDsOut"),
    hr(),
    sliderInput(inputId="slider1", label="My value will be bookmarked", min=0, max=10, value=5),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  bookmarkingWhitelist <- c("slider1")

  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })

  ExcludedIDs <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)

  observe({
    toExclude <- setdiff(names(input), bookmarkingWhitelist)
    setBookmarkExclude(toExclude)
    ExcludedIDs(toExclude)
  })

  output$ExcludedIDsOut <- renderText({ 
    paste("ExcludedIDs:", paste(ExcludedIDs(), collapse = ", "))
  })

  observeEvent(input$addSlider, {
    output$slider2 <- renderUI({ 
      sliderInput(inputId="slider2", label="My value will not be bookmarked", min=0, max=10, value=5)
    })
  }, once = TRUE)

}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```