# How to run read.csv data in dynamic input of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Fowllowing the description of dynamic shiny app at topic [[R Shiny Dynamic Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094718/r-shiny-dynamic-input/36096128#36096128][1])
, i want to get a data into shiny app. I wrote in ui.R

```
library(fPortfolio)
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Portfolio optimization"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("numInputs", "A number of stocks", 2),
      # place to hold dynamic inputs
      uiOutput("inputGroup")
    ),


mainPanel(
  tabPanel("Trading Statistics",
           fixedRow(
             column(8,
                    fixedRow(column(4,tableOutput("tablePerformance")),
                             column(4,tableOutput("tableRisk"))),
                    fixedRow(column(4,tableOutput("tableDaily")),
                             column(4,tableOutput("tableMonthly"))))
             ))
  )
  )
))
```

and in server.r

```
library(fPortfolio)
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$numInputs, {
    output$inputGroup = renderUI({
      input_list <- lapply(1:input$numInputs, function(i) {
        # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
        inputName <- paste("input", i, sep = "")
        textInput(inputName, inputName, value = 1)
      })
      do.call(tagList, input_list)
    })
  })


  data <- read.csv("E:/stock vn data/dulieuvietnam/metastock_all_data.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  Tickers <- data[!duplicated(data$X.Ticker.),1]
  Tickers <- subset(Tickers,substr(Tickers,1,1)!= "^")
  PriceList <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(Tickers)){
    PriceList[[i]] <- subset(data[,c(2,6)],data$X.Ticker. == Tickers[i])
    names(PriceList[[i]]) <- c("Date",Tickers[i])
    PriceList[[i]][PriceList[[i]]==0]<-NA
    PriceList[[i]] <- na.locf(PriceList[[i]])
  }
  PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]]<-subset(data[,c(2,6)],data$X.Ticker. == "^VNINDEX")
  names(PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]]) <- c("Date","VNINDEX")
  PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]][PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]]==0]<-NA
  PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]] <- na.locf(PriceList[[(length(Tickers)+1)]])

  dataPrice <- PriceList[[1]]
  for (k in 2:length(PriceList)){
    dataPrice <-merge(dataPrice,PriceList[[k]],all=TRUE)
  }

    output$tablePerformance<-renderTable({

  })
})
```

.
When i run runApp(), the app only shows input with label "A number of stocks" that has default value is 2. However, interface of app did not show two text input.
Please help me!

Comment: Try to run all code below `read.csv` (including that line) within an `observe`.

Comment: I have just tried as your guess, but the app did not show two text input. It only shows input with label "A number of stocks" that has default value is 2.

Comment: If you comment off everything below (including) `read.csv` line, does it show two inputs? I've tested here and it does.

Comment: If I comment off everything below (including) read.csv line, does it show two inputs, it show two inputs. However, I want to include data in shiny app. How can I do that?

Comment: Must be something wrong with that section of code, because I used `read.csv` on a test file and render it as table and I still get two inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your guess! i found a problem with it, and i fix it by reinstalling shiny package from cran.