# Download files form server in Shiny R

Tags: r, download, shiny-server, shiny

I'd like to create app which allows to download any kind of files that I place in the directory.

The only way I came up with is to use `html tags`. For example:
`tags$a(href = "file_name.extension", "Press for downloading" )`.

However, I have 10 files and placing 10 links is not appropriate solution.

Parallel example what I'd like to do can be found [here.](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html) In this case `data.frames` are used, not files form the server.

Is there a way to create a `function` in `server` side which allows to select file and then to download it using one `button`, such as in the example for `data.frames`?

I'd like to replicate `data.frames` example for any kind of files, such as `xlsx`, `png`, `zip`,...

Also, I enclose code example so it'll be easier to understand the problem.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


# Header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sm <- sidebarMenu(
  menuItem(
    text="Download",
    tabName="Download",
    icon=icon("home")
  )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sm)

# Body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

  # Layout  --------------------------------------------  

  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName="Download",

      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(

            h1("Some files to download:"),
#### 2 files for downloading
            tags$a(href = "cat1.xlsx", "Cat picture" ),
            HTML("<br/>"),
            tags$a(href = "cat2.xlsx", "Second cat picture" )

        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

I've found out how to solve it using `html`.

This piece of code solves the issue, however, is there a way how to optimize it using `server`?

```
HTML("
<h2>Some files to download:</h2>
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>Files to download
    <span class='caret'></span></button>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='cat1.xlsx'>Download Cat 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='cat2.xlsx'>Download Cat 2</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>")
```

Comment: How about making a checkbox?

Comment: I'd like to replicate `data.frames` example for any kind of files, such as `xlsx`, `png`, `zip`,...

Comment: I think you can use `list.files()` and `downloadButton` to create a list of download buttons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094718/r-shiny-dynamic-input/36096128#36096128 for an example of auto rendering multiple UI objects.