# Using a for in Shiny with a user input

Tags: for-loop, input, shiny, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown Shiny file and I want to use a for so that it shows the same input boxes repeatedly depending on another user input as follows:

```
fluidRow(
numericInput("NFills", 
    label = h3("Number of Different Fills"), 
    value = 1)
)

for(i in 1:input$NFills)
{
    fluidRow(
    column(3, 
    numericInput(paste("Qty",1), 
    label = h3("Quantity"), 
    value = 0)),
    column(3, 
    numericInput(paste("Price",1), 
    label = h3("Price"), 
    value = 1)),
    column(3, 
    numericInput(paste("Numerator",1), 
    label = h3("Numerator"), 
    value = 0))
)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual question? You can use a for loop together with `renderUI` to create dynamic numbers of input.

Comment: The question is how can I make it possible, I'm running Shiny on R Markdown and with the shown code an error appears. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an similar example in Shiny, and you should be able to migrate this to RMarkdown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094718/r-shiny-dynamic-input/36096128#36096128

Comment: That really helps.Thanks!