# Using dynamic input from tagList to renderTable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

What I am trying to do is have the user specify the number of groups then, based on the number of groups specified, the UI generates a `numericInput` for each group. Then I want to use that value to do some other operations (in this example, I'm making a table of means). Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094718/r-shiny-dynamic-input), I was able to make it return some text, but not use that label as input for anything else.

When I try to use that information (i.e., as reactive conductor), I get a "replacement has length zero" error. It seems shiny is not recognizing the updated UI. I know it probably has something to do with using `reactive`, but I can't figure out why it's not working. Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

# functions ---------------------------------------------------------------
## generic function that creates an input from an i
make_list = function(i, idname, labelname){
  idname <- paste(idname, i, sep = "")
  div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 45%;",
      numericInput(idname, labelname, 0))
}

## make function that can be used within a loop
list_loop = function(i) {
  make_list(i, "mean", "Mean of Group ")
}


# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("A Test Page"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 8,
        #### UI for groups
       numericInput("groups", "How many groups?", 4),
       hr(),
       uiOutput("inputMean")),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(width = 4,
              h3("Data Preview"),
              #textOutput("inputValues"),
              tableOutput("table"))
    )
)


# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server = function(input, output) {

  ## loop through # of groups for all i and make the UI
  ## this is passed back to the UI
  observeEvent(input$groups, 
      {
        output$inputMean = renderUI(
          {
            mean_list <- 1:input$groups %>% map(~list_loop(.x))
            do.call(tagList, mean_list)
          }
        )
    }
  ) 

  ## return the inputnames
  ## This WORKS
  output$inputValues <- renderText({
    paste(lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("mean", i, sep = "")
      input[[inputName]]
    }))
  })

  make_table = reactive({
    ### prepopulate a table
    d = data.frame(group = 1:input$groups)
    d$means = NA
    paste(lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("mean", i, sep = "")
      # this fails because input is NULL at this point
      d$means[i] = input[[inputName]]
    }))
    d
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    make_table()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your `make_table` with the following, it works.

I added a `req` that checks if all the input is present, so it won't throw errors anymore. Then, I filled `d$means` using the `lapply` you created.

```
  make_table = reactive({
    req(input$groups, input[[paste("mean", input$groups, sep = "")]])
    ### prepopulate a table
    d = data.frame(group = 1:input$groups)
    d$means = lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("mean", i, sep = "")
      # this fails because input is NULL at this point
      input[[inputName]]
    })
    d
  })
```