# Shiny, create vector or list from several optional textInput fields

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build a command and let the user define up to 5 optional arguments (params1 to params5) that get added to the command string separated with " -p ".

> -p var1=1 -p var2="one" -p option1="null" -p option2="no comment"

ui:

```
                            textInput("params1", label = "#1"),
                            textInput("params2", label = "#2"),
                            textInput("params3", label = "#3"),
                            textInput("params4", label = "#4"),
                            textInput("params5", label = "#5"),
```

For instance, in my current interface, the user could leave them all empty or fill one or more.

Is there an elegant way (better than my long & failing code) to handle them using some apply magic and consider only textInput fields where the user has put some content?

I tried to use get(paste0("input$params", i)) to name the 5 inputs and get the 5 values but shiny complains

server:

```
params <- reactive({
    parlist <- list()
    parstring <- ""
    for (i in 1:5){
        parval <- try(get(paste0("input$params",i)))
        if (exists(parval)){
            parlist <- c(parlist, parval)
        }
    }
    if (exists(parlist)){
        parstring=paste0(" -p ", stri_join_list(parlist, collapse= " -p "))
    } else {
        parstring=""
    }
    return(parstring)
})
```

resulting in

```
Error in get(paste0("input$params", i)) : 
  object 'input$params1' not found
Error in get(paste0("input$params", i)) : 
  object 'input$params2' not found
Error in get(paste0("input$params", i)) : 
  object 'input$params3' not found
Error in get(paste0("input$params", i)) : 
  object 'input$params4' not found
Error in get(paste0("input$params", i)) : 
  object 'input$params5' not found
Warning: Error in exists: invalid first argument
```

My problem now is to test and add existing textInputs values (input$params1 ... input$params5) into a vector or list that I can then use in the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it:

```r
params <- reactive({
  parlist <- Filter(
    nchar, vapply(1:5, function(i) input[[paste0("params", i)]], character(1))
  )
  if(length(parlist)){
    paste0("-p ", parlist, collapse = " ")
  }else{
    ""
  }
})
```

Comment: I adapted very slightly to fit my needs ```paste0(" -p ", parlist, collapse = "")```

Comment: I also found a nice example to create the 5 (or more) textFields dynamically (long searched to finally find this one :-) => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094718/r-shiny-dynamic-input/36096128#36096128